# php dynamic links from search form results

Tags: php, mysqli

A search form on my site produces results as a list of items which are then linked to an description page using the item id. Originally when I opened the species.php page from the link none of the variables which make up the page were shown.
I have now found the error, it was in the link to the url.
   The following code now works

```
<?php
    require '../assets/includes/conn.inc.php';
    ?>
         <div >
                <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
                  <fieldset>
                    <h4>Search </h4>
                    <input name="search" placeholder="Enter Name Here" type="text">
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                  </fieldset>
                </form>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h4>Search Results</h4>
                <?php
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            $search = "%{$_POST['search']}%";
        }
        $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT id, species, vern  FROM marine WHERE species LIKE ? OR vern LIKE ? ORDER by species"); {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $search, $search);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $numRows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $species, $vern); 
        {
          while ($stmt->fetch()) {
         echo <a href=\"species.php?id=$id\">$species - $vern</a><br/>";
          }}
        }
        $stmt->close();
        ?>
              </div>
```

Thank you to everyone who had a look and commented.

Comment: Does the link contain the information you expect?  What is the exact URL?  Which line is 52?  Where is `$row` defined that it should be usable on line 52?

Comment: Can I see what's on line:52?

Comment: If `$_GET['id']` is not set in your code, you will get this notice, assuming line 52 is the first <div> line. In this case the entire HTML should also be inside the if.

Comment: Sorry line 52:
<div><?php echo $row['species']; ?></em> <?php echo $row['author']; ?></div>.